# Can I publish Google Home application for limited users?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I would like to publish Google Home application for limited users(account or device).

Can I do such thing?
I think that one way is to use test draft, but it can be used only 30days.
However I can extend expiry with gactions command update, I would rather not do it as much as possible.

So if someone teach me about publishing GH application for limited users , I would be very happy.

Answer (score 2):

For a draft (aka test version) you can add testers in the Actions console. For a published version you can use oAuth to limit access. There there is no published but "private" (my word) option.

Answer (score 1):

Google supports Alpha and Beta testing for your action. I think that is exactly what you want to do.
You can find the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments).